# md5 hash is different on a file split, cat back again

Tags: shell, md5

Here's an excerpt of the commands I ran as I `split` and then `cat` a file:

```
sh-3.2# split -b 600m bt4-final.iso 

sh-3.2# ls -hal
total 6132096
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   staff   204B Jan 12 19:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 alien  staff   442B Jan 12 19:54 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root   staff   1.5G Jan 12 19:56 bt4-final.iso
-rw-r--r--   1 root   staff   600M Jan 12 19:58 xaa
-rw-r--r--   1 root   staff   600M Jan 12 19:59 xab
-rw-r--r--   1 root   staff   297M Jan 12 19:59 xac

sh-3.2# cat $(ls -t x*) > bt4-final-reasembled.iso

sh-3.2# ls
bt4-final-reasembled.iso    xaa          xac
bt4-final.iso               xab

sh-3.2# md5 bt4*
MD5 (bt4-final-reasembled.iso) = edd4f24f3abcabb8a447a69eaa30ff39
MD5 (bt4-final.iso) = af139d2a085978618dc53cabc67b9269
```

Why is it that the MD5 hash is different for what is essentially the same file?

Comment: Because MD5 still has a small chance of not generating a collision :P

Comment: I'd like to see the output of 2 commands: 1. `ls -l bt4*` 2. `cmp bt4*`

Answer (score 14):

You're catting the files together in the wrong order, owing to the unnecessary `ls -t`.

`cat x* > out.iso` would do just fine and give the correct output. POSIX guarantees that globbing will give you files in sorted order.

Comment: +1 I just noticed the `-t`, but you beat me to answering.

Answer (score 5):

You were reconstituting the files in the wrong order. With the use of `ls -t`, files are listed newest (i.e., last split chunk, in your case) first.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are combining them in the same order?  If you combine them in a different order, you should certainly expect the MD5 sum to be different.

If you combined them in the same order, the bits would be the same, and you would get the same md5 sum.  If the bits are not the same, it probably means your RAM is bad.  See [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/).

Comment: yes, maybe "ls -t" is not so good. should be ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, its because of `ls -t`, you are sorting by time, so last one before first in resamble file

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not putting them back together in the same order that they started in. You're right, if you reassemble them correctly, the md5sum should match. Here's a trivial example:

```
$ cat > xaa
This is the first file
$ cat > xab
This is the second file
$ cat > xac
This is the third file.
$ cat $(ls -t x*) > final.txt
$ cat final.txt
This is the third file.
This is the second file
This is the first file
```

Try this:

```
$ cat x* > good.txt
$ cat good.txt
This is the first file
This is the second file
This is the third file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow some bits got corrupt, got reordered, got added, or got removed in the process of splitting and rejoining.